# Get app engine info via api commands

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Seems like google cloud's shell commands are super limited.

I can see docs about using appcfg.py to upload and download code from app engine, but what are the commands to just get basic info about it?

Is there a list services command? Or a get running versions command? I still don't understand where the app engine code I upload lives.

What are the commands to just "poke" app engine stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get info about what `appcfg.py` can do:

```
$ appcfg.py help
Usage: appcfg.py help <action>

appcfg.py: error: Expected a single action argument.  Must be one of:
...
  list_versions: List all uploaded versions for an app.
...

$ appcfg.py help list_versions
Usage: appcfg.py [options] list_versions [directory]

List all uploaded versions for an app. 

The 'list_versions' command outputs the uploaded versions for each module of
an application in YAML. The YAML is in formatted as an associative array,
mapping module_ids to the list of versions uploaded for that module. The
default version will be first in the list.
...
```

A bit newer than `appcfg.py` and the officially recommended one these days (but still not covering all the stuff from the Console) is the [`gcloud`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/) CLI from the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/) (and in particular the [`gcloud app`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/) submenu for GAE apps).

Your uploaded code lives in the cloud :) Donno exactly where, but you can see it in the Console's [Debug](https://console.cloud.google.com/debug) page. Not directly accessible from the cloud shell's VM (AFAIK). If you want to access it in the cloud shell you need to download it from your app to your "cloud homedir" (using one of the 2 utilities).

As for "poking", you have to be very specific as different kinds of poking are done in different ways (many in the GUI only). Probably better to do it in a separate question (or questions).

Comment: OK that answers my question. Guess I missed some docs "gcloud app" seems to give me what I want- why couldn't I find that!?